# copying and pasting into another cell

Tags: vba, excel

we are trying to go through a range of cells looking for a particular string.  In one case the string is accessibility but the whole string is accessibility3.2.  Then we want to paste the string to a cell on another sheet.

then the next time through the loop it could be accessibility5.8

here is some code we have written:

```
srtDate = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Website Quality").Cells(9, 3).Value

rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Column(1).Find(What:=Accessibility, _
                    LookIn:=x1Values, LookAt:=x1Whole, MatchCase:=True)

srtDate.Value = rng.Value
```

any help would be great 
Thanks

Comment: What's the problem with the code you have? Do you get an error? If yes, what is it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this is what you want (I'm assuming "Accesibility" is a literal string).

Change

`rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Column(1).Find(What:=Accessibility, _
                    LookIn:=x1Values, LookAt:=x1Whole, MatchCase:=True)`

to

```
Set rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1).Find(What:="Accessibility", _
                LookIn:=x1Values, LookAt:=x1Part, MatchCase:=True)
```

Comment: @TimWilliams, good catch Tim, I missed that!  I've corrected my post, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your `.Find` is obviously the `Range.Find` method because it contains arguments that aren't present in the `WorksheetFunction.Find` method.

The `Range.Find` method requires an expression that evaluates to a **Range Object**.

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").column(1)
```

doesn't evaluate to a range. You can test this by entering in the Immediate pane

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").column(1).select
```

which will return an error 438

> Object doesn't support this method or property

whereas

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").select
```

works just fine in the Immediate pane so replace `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Column(1)` with `ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")`

The return from a `Range.Find` method is a range so the variable that takes the return should be defined as a range

```
Dim rng as Range
```

If you don't have `Option Explicit` at the top of your module, **all variables are assumed by VBA to be of Variant Type** but the Variant Type is not interchangeable with Object Types.

If you set your VBA IDE to always "Require variable declaration" via Tools > Options > Editor Tab `Option Explicit` will be added to every module in your projects and you will not suffer from incorrect variable calls.

Now **Objects** can't be assigned by using `ObjectName = ...`. They must be **Set** using `Set ObjectName = ...` and the return must be of the same type as the object being set.

If you `Dim rng as Range` then the method on the right side of the `Set rng = ...` must return an object of the same type or an error will occur.

Your `What:=Accessibility,` is trying to find the contents of a variable named Accessibility which probably doesn't exist. Find the string `"Accesibility"` will work even if it's embedded within other characters if you `LookAt:=xlPart`.

To summarise:

Define your object `Dim rng as Range`

and change your line

```
rng = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Column(1).Find(What:=Accessibility, _
                LookIn:=x1Values, LookAt:=x1Whole, MatchCase:=True)
```

to:

```
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A")
    Set rng = .Find(what:="Accessibility, LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart)   
End With
```

which should leave you with a `rng.value` that you can use.

Comment: You can also use `With ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2").Columns(1)
`